# Run Podman in Rootless failed on fuse-overlayfs

Tags: podman

I installed Podman on CentOS 7. I can run it under root permission, but failed in a rootless environment.

Here is the command and result:

```
$ podman run -it busybox sh
ERRO[0000] error unmounting /home/chsun/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/ea62672ff47fb673afd59da0bbcc2d4327327949c96193a87ea5042d87af0183/merged: invalid argument 
Error: error mounting storage for container c34523fdee2a01caab4b26575d97ce12fb3af3aabef3eb89941f19944272189f: error creating overlay mount to /home/chsun/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/ea62672ff47fb673afd59da0bbcc2d4327327949c96193a87ea5042d87af0183/merged: using mount program /usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs: fuse: failed to exec fusermount3: No such file or directory
fuse-overlayfs: cannot mount: Operation not permitted
: exit status 1
$
```

Comment: In the error text: _fusermount3: No such file or directory_. On my Fedora 35 laptop that executable is found in the RPM package __fuse3__. Maybe the package is called the same in CentOS 7? Maybe that RPM package is missing?

Comment: I installed fuse3 but problem is not solved.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229782/overlayfs-doesnt-work-with-unprivileged-user-namespace#230951

Answer (score 0):

The error contains `failed to exec fusermount3`

- Have you checked whether you have that executable on your machine?
  If not, check which package it is in.
- Check if it can be run from command line directly.
  If not, check whether all dependencies are available using `ldd fusermount3`
  If dependencies are missing, try to figure out the package they might come with.

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fusermount3.1.html indicates that `libfuse` plays a role. See also https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/fuse-libs-2.9.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

You might want to install it using

```
# yum install fuse-libs
```

If the binary seems ok on your system the problem may be more on the command line that it is invoked with. Unfortunately you did not post that. What remains to be checked then is

- filesystem permissions
- SE Linux permissions
- the podman installation itself (did you configure necessary parameters, like in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`?)